# White noise vs. black noise

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QOnfvWqVoo) excellent lecture ("2d Percolation Revisited") Stanislav Smirnov mentioned the connection of the theory of percolation with the notion of the so called *black noise*—see [at 29:42](https://youtu.be/6QOnfvWqVoo?t=1782) (the notion introduced by Boris Tsirelson). 
I would like to understand various claims which were made in this lecture, in particular:

> Black noise is a noise where there is no spectrum at all […] it is a random field, so it is Fock space and all of that, so it an object from quantum mechanics but which you cannot detect by any linear functional—so harmonic oscilator does not see this.

And also the following:

> Now suppose that you look at percolation as a model where you have some information at every side and you look at connection probabilities—so that's your sigma algebra of events is connection probabilities. So the question is: can you pass to the limit? On a lattice you can do it but is there an object on a plane where at every point you have a bit of information and in the end you end up storing only connection probabilities?

As I understood correctly the answer is YES and the relevant object is the scaling limit of planar percolation which is a black noise.

So to summarize: my question is rather vague so what kind of answer I am expecting? Any comments and remarks clarifying the above two quotes, maybe an explanation "how to think about black noise correctly" and justification of the use of the term "noise" in this context (for example: white noise (for example on the line) is some sort of random function which is a derivative of a random *continuous* function (Brownian motion): in fact this derivative should be understood as a distribution due to the lack of differentiability of Brownian motion—nevertheless it is a (generalized) stochastic process. However for the black noise, as I understood correctly, it is defined only as a family of *sigma fields* not a family of *random variables* which is somehow weaker—is this lack of random *variables* related to the fact that "there is no spectrum at all"?).

Answer (score 8):

Percolation 'noise' is generated by a perfectly good family of random variables, the 'quad-crossing' events. Basically, for every diffeomorphic image of the unit square, this random variable is $1$ if one can cross from the left to the right face traversing only open bonds and $0$ otherwise. Let's call this random variable $X_\phi$ where $\phi$ is the diffeomorphism in question. Now, for any open set $U$, we have a $\sigma$-algebra $F_U$ which is generated by all the $X_\phi$ such that $\phi([0,1]^2) \subset U$. This is a 'noise' in the sense that $F_U$ and $F_V$ are independent if $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

In this context, a 'linear' random variable is a random variable $Y$ such that, for every smooth enough closed curve $\Gamma$, writing $\Gamma_i$ and $\Gamma_e$ for its interior and exterior respectively, one has
$$Y = \mathbf{E}(Y\,|\, F_{\Gamma_i}) + \mathbf{E}(Y\,|\, F_{\Gamma_e})\;.$$
The claim is that $0$ is the only linear random variable, which is the definition of 'black noise'.

This is in stark contrast to 'white noise', for which the space of linear random variables is sufficiently rich to generate the full $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: that's interesting, but to follow up on the question of the OP, how is it related to quantum mechanics?

Comment: Not sure what Stas meant with that remark. The noise being black precisely means that the probability space doesn’t admit a random field that’s compatible with the noise structure...

Comment: It is good to have a concise explanation like this one. (I have no experience in this field and am just curious.) However, I cannot imagine how the event of horizontal (?) traversing can depend on a diffeomorphism, and how you define "left" and "right", especially for an arbitrary diffeomorphic image of the square. Can you detail this? Also, does your comment "the probability space doesn’t admit a random field that’s compatible with the noise structure" mean that there is no nonzero "linear" random variable?

Comment: The left and right faces would the images of the left and right faces of $[0,1]^2$ under $\phi$. Regarding the other comment, I meant that there is no non-zero distribution-valued random variable $\zeta$ such that $\zeta(\psi)$ is $F_{\supp \psi}$-measurable for every test function $\psi$. Modulo some technical analytical regularity requirements, this is essentially the same as not admitting any non-trivial linear random variables as in the answer.

Comment: @MartinHairer : Thank you for this response. I think I understand now what you mean by the left and right faces of a diffeomorphic image of the square. But I still cannot imagine how the event of crossing can be defined so that it may depend on the choice of a diffeomorphic image; shouldn't this event be invariant under diffeomorphisms?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis Why would it be invariant under diffeomorphisms? Percolation certainly isn't. Even under conformal maps, it's only invariant in the sense that the probability will be the same, but it won't be the same random variable.

Comment: @MartinHairer thank you very much for your great answer and the comments. So am I right in the following: for the white noise $\xi$ (say on the plane) one cannot define $\xi(x,y)$ as a random variable but it should be understood as a distribution-so in particular $\xi(f)$ makes sense as a random variable for a test function $f$. For a black noise the situation is similar (you cannot define $X(x,y)$ as a random variable) but this time the relevant index set is the set of all diffeomorphism from the square, i.e. we get a family of random variables but they are not indexed by points in the plane.

Comment: but rather by all diffeomorphisms from the unit square. In this sense we get some family of _functions_ and the main challenge is to give them a meaning as a family of_random variables_ i.e. to define all the relevant measurable structure. This is achieved in the construction of the scaling limit of percolation: once the scaling limit is defined the conclusion that percolation is a black noise is a corrolary of this. Is the right way of thinking?

Comment: The fact that percolation is a black noise certainly doesn't follow from 'soft' considerations like this. We could have generated white noise in a similar way by considering the diffeomorphism-indexed family of RV's $Y_\phi = \xi(\chi_{\phi([0,1]^2)})$ and by having $F_U$ generated by the $Y_\phi$'s such that $\phi([0,1]^2) \subset U$. The noise $F$ generated in this way is still white even though one can't really distinguish it from percolation from a purely formalistic point of view.

Comment: @MartinHairer : You asked: "Why would it be invariant under diffeomorphisms?" -- As best I can imagine, just by definition. I don't see any other way to define the event of crossing from left to right for a diffeomorphic image of the square. So, essentially, my question was (and still is) this: What is the formal definition of the event of crossing from left to right for a diffeomorphic image of the square?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I think that this diffeomorphism is fixed and for any fixed diffeo you get the event of crossing the image of the square under this diffeo. In fact in the Schramm's and Smirnov's paper they construct the scaling limit using all possible diffeos (in fact they use homeomorphic images) which as they pointed out in the paper ,,introduce some redundancy [...] but avoid certain technical difficulties''.

Comment: I thought a percolation configuration was a subset of the unit square, which was then diffeo-mapped together with the square. Therefore, I thought the event of crossing should be the same for all diffeo-images of the square. Now I have looked at the paper by Schramm and Smirnov. It seems that their percolation configurations are subsets of a plane domain $D$. It also seems that, for each such configuration $\omega$, they consider the **intersections** (?) of $\omega$ with various homeo-images $Q\subseteq D$ of the square and then see which of intersections $\omega\cap Q$ are crossings of $Q$.